# How to compute weighted average of tensor A along an axis with weights specified by tensor B in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, weighted-average

I am trying to apply a weighted average scheme on RNN output.
RNN output is represented by tensor `A` having dimension `(a,b,c)`.
I can simply take `tf.reduce_mean(A,axis=1)` to get the tensor `C` having dimension `(a,c)`.

However, I want to do the "weighted average" of tensor `A` along `axis = 1`.
Weights are specified in the matrix `B` having dimension `(d,b)`.

For `d = 1`, I can do `tf.tensordot(A,B,[1,1])` to get the result of dimension `(a,c)`.
Now for `d=a`, I am unable to compute the weighted average.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Try `tf.reduce_sum(A * B[:, :, None], axis=1) / tf.reduce_sum(B, axis=1, keepdims=True)`. If it works, I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: @SiyuanRen can you please explain what it does?

Comment: @SiyuanRen weights are already normalized. So no need for division operation. I think division operation is normalizing weights so that it sums to 1. Can you explain the evaluation of the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get why `B` should have dimensions `(d,b)`. If `B` contains the weights to do a weighted average of A across only one dimension, `B` only has to be a vector `(b,)`, not a matrix.

If `B` is a vector, you can do:

`C = tf.tensordot(A,B,[1,0])` to get a vector `C` of shape `(a,c`) which contains the weighted average of `A` across `axis=1` using the weights specified in `B`.

**Update:**

You can do something like:

```
A = A*B[:,:,None]
```

which is doing element wise multiplication of `A` and `B`, where `B` stores the weights given to each element in `A`. 
Then:

```
C = tf.reduce_mean(A,axis=1)
```

will do the weighted average since each element in `A` has been multiplied by its weight.

Comment: I have obtained the results for the d=1 case. I need d=a case because I have weights for each input and batch size is specified by a and d.

Comment: Ok, sorry, then you can do something like: `A = A*B[:,:,None]` (this is doing element wise multiplication of `A` and `B`, where `B` stores the weights given to each element in `A`) and then `C = tf.reduce_mean(A,axis=1)`, which will do the weighted mean since each element in `A` has been multiplied by its weight.

Answer (score 1):

Since `B` is already normalized, the answer is

```
tf.reduce_sum(A * B[:, :, None], axis=1)
```

Indexing with `None` adds a new dimension, a behavior inherited from numpy.`B[:,:, None]` adds a last dimension so the result has shape `(a, b, 1)`. You can achieve the same thing with `tf.expand_dims`, whose name may make more sense to you.

`A` has shape `(a, b, c)` while `B[:, :, None]` has shape `(a, b, 1)`. When they are multiplied, expanded B will be treated as having shape `(a, b, c)` too, with the last dimension being `c` copies of the same value. This is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Because of how broadcasting works, the same answer also works if `B` has shape `(1, b)`.