# How to get the Weighted Average Mean in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0

from example_data below I need **sum_product(x,y)/sum(y)** - *having x & y as Input.*.. probably this part of model can even be trainable=False, but anyway, is there a simplier way to do such calculation (either from 1 tensor at all or at least from such separate tensors for vars & weights) ?
*If there could be more beautiful Graph for such Task*, than I've created ?
I could have written Only such long code (for such a simple thing)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

x= np.array([[1100, 1200, 1300, 1400]] ) # vals
y= np.array([[10, 50, 30, 5]] ) # weights

inpS= tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,), batch_size=1, name='inp1', dtype='float32')
inpW= tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,), batch_size=1, name='inp2', dtype='float32')
dot_product = tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=1, normalize=False, trainable=False)([inpS, inpW]) 
wsum = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( lambda z: K.sum(z, axis=1, keepdims=True))(inpW)
con= tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([dot_product, wsum])  #for Multiple input into Lambda layer
wa = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0][0]/x[0][1])(con)

model = tf.keras.Model([inpS, inpW], wa)
model.predict([x,y])
```

RES should be:
117000/95=1231.5789794921875

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399197/how-to-compute-weighted-average-of-tensor-a-along-an-axis-with-weights-specified

Comment: Not exactly. Your link shows just weighted vars in output, but I need Weighted Average Mean value of the whole Range... (resulting ~1231)...I've corrected the title of the topic

Answer (score 0):

really, very easy to simplify:

```
Weighted_Av_Mean = tf.reduce_sum(weights * x) / tf.reduce_sum(weights)
tf.print(Weighted_Av_Mean)
```

solved due to comment's directive...
OR even in such a way:

```
# cast x & weights numpy_arrays first
x = tf.dtypes.cast(x,tf.float32)
weights = tf.dtypes.cast(weights,tf.float32)
# gives mean & variance
WAMean2= tf.nn.weighted_moments(
    x, axes=[1], frequency_weights= weights, keepdims=False, name=None
)
tf.print('mean: ',WAMean2[0])
```